# Sleep a random time with nanosleep()

Tags: c, random, sleep

I know it's a newbie question but I am struggling with this and don't understand `nanosleep()` well enough.

How can I make a process sleep a random time between 100 and 200 miliseconds?

Comment: What is there to not to understand?

Comment: imo, this question is trickier than it appears - is nanosleep actually useful here, if we want to sleep amounts of milliseconds? what kind of precision do we need? what kind of distribution do we expect? if we need "exact" nanosecond precision, how can we generate random numbers between 10^8 and 2*10^8, which feels large enough to run into problems with RAND_MAX, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A millisecond is (corrected, sorry, blah...) 1,000,000 nanoseconds. Multiply appropriately.

Comment: Downvoting is a bit cruel -- keshlam is only off by a factor of 10 :)

Comment: Bah. That's what I get for typing when half alseep.